# Remove outer jquery UI dialog scroll and add inner scroll to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to remove the outer dialog scroll bar and make a section inside the dialog scrollable.  I was able to remove the outer dialog scroll bar by setting `overflow:visible` on the dialog but i tried to put `overflow:hidden` on the div I want scrollable inside the dialog but it did not work.  It actually cuts off the div till the dialog runs out of height.  Any suggestions?

```
**EDIT**
JSFIDDLE
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lqthfqg/14/

In the fiddle i want to freeze the top section and scroll the bottom half of the section.  I label which section i want to freeze and which area i want to be scrollable.  Overflow is auto in the fiddle example just so

Comment: Can you also post some code, may be a fiddle?

Comment: @Abhi I added a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a fixed height and set `overflow-y` to `auto` for the div you want to be scrollable.

```
 <div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pba8rhpd/1/)

---

The [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) style defaults to `visible`, which means the content will not be clipped and may be rendered outside the content box. If you set it to `auto`, the browser will clip the content and add scrollbars when needed. If you want the scrollbars even when they are not needed, set it to `scroll`.